Change address input field via JS and inform React state about it
I want to change the value of the address input field in the new WooCommerce blocks checkout via a simple JS snippet.
My problem is, that I am not able to inform the React state about this change and the field value does not change for React.
I tried this code:
// Function to change the address field and notify the React state
function updateBillingAddress(newAddress) {
    // Select the input field
    const addressInput = document.querySelector('#billing-address_1');
    if (addressInput) {
        // Update the input field value
        addressInput.value = newAddress;
        
        // Create and dispatch an 'input' event to notify React of the change
        const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
        addressInput.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}

// Call the function with the desired new address
updateBillingAddress('test 123');

I am looking for an option that works inside a code snippet or even better from the Chrome dev tools console. Is that even possible?
